# TCL: Nested Associative Arrays

Tags: tcl

Is it possible to do nested associative arrays in Tcl? I know I can use 'dict' in tcl8.5 or higher, but my code needs to run on tcl8.4.

I'm looking to do this:

```
array set A {}
array set tmp {...}
array set tmp1 {...}
array set A($foo) tmp
array set A($foo1) tmp1
```

So foo/foo1 are keys and their values are associative arrays. In python, this would be like a dict of dicts.

I am trying the above but tcl is complaining A($foo)/A($foo1) is not an array.

Comment: No, tcl arrays are strictly one-dimensional. You can construct complicated strings for the keys to fake multi-dimensionality: `set A(foo,bar,baz) qux`

Comment: Or, array values can be lists, so `set A($foo) [array get tmp]`

Comment: My best attempt was `upvar 0 arrayvar(key) refvar` ; `array set refvar {key value}`. It does not work: refvar does not exist yet, but is already blocked to not become an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tcl's arrays *cannot* be nested (except in very old versions of Tcl, where there were bugs which let you do it). You can often use a composite key such as `a,b,c` (or `$a,$b,$c`) to achieve a similar effect, but that's really just leveraging the fact that keys are *general strings* and not numbers or simple words.

```
set A(123,$xyz) "the quick brown $fox"
set B($pqr,456) "the lazy dogs"
```

In addition to this, you can't really put references to variables in variables. You'd have to do some additional munging:

```
foreach {key value} [array get tmp1] {
    set A($foo,$key) $value
}
```

Tcl 8.5's dictionaries (where the mapping is a value, not a variable collection) would indeed be a better solution for the things you're looking to do, particularly since 8.4 is now entirely end-of-lifed (and I know of some really nasty bugs in it that won't be fixed). I think there's a `dict` package that implements a partial backport of the functionality for 8.4, but I'm not entirely sure about that as I didn't do the packaging and had already moved on to 8.5 at that point; it won't be maintained…